# Intent to open Truecaller App from Android App

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to open Truecaller App when someone tap on mobile number in my app. Is there any specific Intent to open Truecaller App like Whatsapp?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

I used this code to open dialer which is not as much effective for me.

Please help me if there is any other option to open Truecaller App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed setting up the Truecaller app package name

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", "PHONE NUMBER", null))

        intent.setPackage("com.truecaller")
        intent?.let { startActivity(it) }
```